# HTML5 and Web Workers on IOS

Tags: jquery, ios, html, web-worker

I'm working on building IOS applications using jQuery and HTML5. Recently I learned that [HTML5 Web Workers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/) provide a great deal of flexibility for Javascript to perform multi-threaded programming, which is quite awesome.

So, does IOS support web workers, and how can I add them to my IOS applications?

Comment: Your question is currently very unclear...please try to improve it a little.

Comment: thank you Mr.Purmou but i couldn't get answer

Comment: @user1070642, do you have any such application example, I do require the same

Answer (score 0):

[Caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) claims that IOS5 supports Web Workers:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=web

A simple example of Web Worker code can be found here:

- http://www.answers.com/topic/web-worker

Give it a try and see if you can get it working.